# Run Cron Every Hour Debian

Tags: linux, debian, cron

How can I setup a cron job in debian to run a certain url once every hour. There`s no control panel or anything.

Comment: Same as on every other distro.

Comment: where`s the file located

Answer (score 6):

You can do that in different ways:

- Make a simple script to run the command and copy it to `/etc/cron.hourly` (don't forget to add the execute permission on it).
- Add a snippet of `crontab` to `/etc/cron.d`.
- Use `crontab -e` as root and add a line to it executing the command directly.

To access an URL you can use `links`, `lynx`, `wget`, `curl` and other text mode browsers. Each one will have it's quirks. I suppose `curl` or `wget` can be the easier ones to use.

I strongly recommend you to read [this article](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/56/Command_scheduling_with_cron) as well as the [cron manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5).

Answer (score 4):

Edit `/etc/crontab` and add a line like the following:

```
0 * * * * root /path/to/executable
```

Or you can put it in your user crontab by running `crontab -e` and add the same line but omit the username field.

Of course, as others have said, you can add a script or symlink to `/etc/cron.hourly`.

Comment: Isn't that one asterik too much?

Answer (score 1):

[Command scheduling with cron](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/56). Take a look at /etc/cron.hourly. Everything you place in there will get executed each and every hour.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the answer [here](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/schedulejobs.htm), though the above comments lay it out nicely already.